# Is "I laugh 10 minutes" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I think it should be

> *"I laugh for 10 minutes"*

and yet online I found versions with no *for*:  "I laugh 10 minutes".  Is that form grammatical?

Comment: Without simply *for*, or have you found *I laugh 10 minutes* as your question title states?  "I laughed 10 minutes" is grammatical; "I laugh 10 minutes" is not because of the tense of *laugh* on its own.

Comment: It _can_ be grammatical – it depends on the context. _I laugh 10 minutes_ sounds awkward by itself, but consider: _I laugh ten minutes each day. I laugh ten minutes every time I hear that joke. Whenever I listen to Steven Wright, I laugh ten minutes or more, but she never laughs more than ten seconds. What's her problem?_  All of those sound fine in context.

Comment: sorry for the confusion... The title question felt so strange that I automatically put it past in the body. It's an example for some grammar explanation I do and I want to have the least info possible in there, that's why I chose present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I laugh 10 minutes* is grammatical, but is unlikely to be found in isolation. There would have to be some context such as *I laugh 10 minutes every day whether I feel like it or not, because it keeps me sane.*

Comment: Barrie: Good to know you chuckle 10 minutes a day!  We wouldn't want to lose you.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it provides context that de-oddyfies mmy version. That is helpful... credit goes also to J.R. though who gave a number of similar examples in a comment. And of course @Brett ... thanks for the quick response. Based on that I continued the article I was writing :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's grammatical. It's very common for a noun phrase like *10 minutes* to be used as an adjunct (or "adverbial") as it is here. Consider the following examples:

- *He arrived **the day before yesterday***
- *I saw her **three times**.*
- *He ran **10 miles**.*
- *She worked **all night**.*

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP. The question is in the title; the sentence in the body is presumably well known to be correct by the OP.

Comment: I was going to question OP on that.  OP quotes *I laughed for 10 minutes* but says that s/he has seen versions without *for*, not without 'ed' *and* 'for'.

Comment: what does OP stand for :)

Comment: @Mitch: No misunderstanding. The sentence in the title is grammatical and is analogous to the examples I provided.

Comment: @Emanuel: I take *OP* to stand for *original poster.*

Comment: The OP's title is "I __laugh__ 10 minutes", present tense. All yours are past tense. At the time I commented (after your initial answer), the body said "I laughed for 10 minutes". The first is wrong the second is correct, the edited version "I laugh for 10 minutes" is wrong. None of your (correct sounding) examples matches the current OP title or body.

Comment: @Mitch: The tense isn't relevant. Both present and past tense are grammatical as J.R.'s comment on the original post shows.

Comment: Sure tense is relevant. Yours are grammatical when they stand alone, but the OP's does not.

Comment: @Mitch: Tense is irrelevant to the grammaticality of omitting a preposition. If *"He ran 10 miles"* is okay, then so is *"He runs 10 miles"*, *"He runs half an hour"*, *"He waits a few minutes"*, etc. OP's version is just a little odd, without a decent supporting context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The sentence "I laugh for 10 minutes." (what is in the title and now in the body) is, as it stands, unacceptable English. Sure you can add some phrases to it to make it acceptable, and that nuance is useful to add to an explanation, but "I laugh for 10 minutes" is still not grammatical by itself which contradicts your logic. Language rules are sometimes logical and sometimes not. This is one time where the transformation doesn't work.

Comment: @Mitch: So what rule does it violate? And who said it was a sentence and not just part of a sentence?

Comment: @BrettReynolds: Normal question/answer rhetoric says it was a stand alone sentence. Which of the eight possibilities: "I laugh/laughed  for/(null) 10 minutes all night/every day/(null)." do you find correct English or not? That's native reporting data. -Then- you make the rule. The semantics  of "I laugh" is not the same as "I am laughing" and is closer to "I laugh sometimes". Despite that all you examples are correct English, they don't parallel/match the OP's example.

Comment: @Mitch: OP only asks if *"for"* is **grammatically** required in this particular string of words. Whether or not it can stand alone as a sentence isn't at issue. Nor imho does it matter that *usually* we would include the preposition in this case - OP clearly knows that already, or he wouldn't be asking. It so happens that with some verbs *(run, laugh, read)* and a duration, we're much less likely to omit *"for"* than others *(wait, drive, live)*. But this is just a matter of idiomatic usage, not grammar.

Answer (score 0):

"I laugh ten minutes." with a full stop at the end is not correct. Moreover, it is difficult to see what this sentence is supposed to mean, given the use of the present tense. It logically does not make sense.

"I laughed for ten minutes." is correct.